# How do I put labels on bars in a horizontal bar chart such that they are centered within the bar?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I am aware of nodes near choords, which is sufficient if the placement of the label is supposed to be relative only to the end node of a bar. What I am trying to do, however, is to have the label centered within the bar. Is there a way to do this?

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1   0   0.1
2   1   \pi
3   2   \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xbar stacked, 
    nodes near coords=$\pgfplotspointmeta$,
    nodes near coords align={left},
    point meta=explicit symbolic] 
 \addplot table [meta index=2] {data.dat}; 
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It draws the labels (0.1, pi, pi/2) to the left of the end of the the respective bar. What I want is for the labels to be centered within the bar.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can play with?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I edited the question and it now includes a simple example. I hope this clarifies the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was right, except that you missed to set `compat=1.9`. So here a bit modified version of your code and the result.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.9,
    }
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    1   0   0.1
    2   1   \pi
    3   2   \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            xbar stacked,
            nodes near coords=$\pgfplotspointmeta$,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
        ]
            \addplot table [meta index=2] {data.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Wow, I would never have guessed that compat=1.9 changes the semantics of my code so drastically. Perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jan-OliverKaiser, you are welcome. This is explained in the section ["Stacked Bar Plots and Nodes Near Coords" on page 96 of the manual (v1.13)](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=96). And if you find my answer useful, you can -- besides marking the question as solved -- also vote it up, if it was useful by hitting the upwards arrow ;)